# What is pebble-method of counting?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, natural-numbers, number-systems

I read about this as:

The tokens of different sizes and shapes were given different values( say a stuck shape for 1, a pellet for 10, a ball for 100....)

I'm wondering, how could they have imagine 100 and so on....cause I read that they had to develop linguistics in order to have idea over numbers greater than 4.

How did Babylonians use base 60?

Comment: I never heard of that. Do you have any description ?

Comment: Maybe useful [Abacus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abacus)

Comment: Abacuses made us able to feel the quantity. But how did we give stones the respective quantities, Mauro?

Comment: " I read that they had to develop linguistics in order to have idea over numbers greater than 4." Do you think that it is possible to count without language ?

Comment: Good book to start with: K.Menninger, [Number Words and Number Symbols: A Cultural History of Numbers](https://books.google.it/books?id=PKGozmluj-IC&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: If the quantity is too large for our hands or any of the things we can use...then it'd be better to develop linguistics or symbols

Comment: I suggest Wikipedia article [Bulla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulla_(seal)) containing clay tokens.